# "If Google was a guy" or "If Google were a guy"?

Tags: grammar

I learnt

- I was
- You were
- He/She/It was

So "If Google was A Guy".

But there is also the song "If I were a boy".

What is right and why?

Comment: See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44706/was-or-were-in-subjunctive-clauses

Comment: I agree this is answered at that link. Just one small point: If I was instead of If I were can indicate or be a marker of level of education. That was not in the link.

Answer (score 1):

A verb in English can have a "mood". The most common mood is the "indicative" used for speaking about facts.  "Google is an internet search engine" or questions "What is Google?".

There is the "imperative" for giving orders "Be good." "Don't be evil"

There is the "subjunctive" that is used for hypothetical situations, wishes, hopes and so on.

One form of the subjunctive is the "were subjunctive" it is used in "if statements" when the condition is unreal.

> If Google were a guy...
>
> If the moon were made of cheese ...
>
> If I were you ...

Now, this grammatical pattern is slowly dying out, replaced by "was". In modern English both

> If Google were a guy ...

and

> If Google was a guy ...

are considered to be grammatical. Using the subjunctive is considered to be more sophisticated, and less casual.

Comment: So to sound sophisticated, you replace every `was` with `were` and stop differentiating between the person it refers to in subjunctive clauses? As in `I were`, `You were`, `He/She/It were`. Is this considered sophisticated even though it makes the language easer, which is contradictory to the self-image of sophisticated speech?

Comment: No. Only in conditional clauses, and only when expressing an unreal condition.  There are other forms of the subjuctive and there is a subjunctive in German (der Konjunktiv).  You may consider if "Hier *sei* nur vermerkt, dass..." is sophisticated.